# MultiAutoCompleteTextView suggestions dropdown always open

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

Is there a way to create a MultiAutoCompleteTextView and keep its suggestion dropdown always open?

Comment: Are you really sure you need that? Shoudn't you use instead a listView or something like that?

Comment: I know that its somewhat weird to use a view like that, but the far as I analyzed my design, its the best choice (if it is possible to do). My issue is the following: I need to create an input field that haves a set of suggestions, each of then comming dinamically from the web and each of then being updatable by the web itself. So, my need to create a textview: to save proccessings and memory from manipulating great portions of data. Thanks for the reply!

Comment: looking for same, let me know if you have got any answer for it

Comment: I need this as well.